# How to check variable value is increasing or decreasing on scrolling?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing some jquery, I have a variable and its values are increasing and decreasing depending upon scrolling. I just want to know when it's value is increasing or decreasing. means when scrolling happens to check it's valued increase or decrease .?
Thanks

Comment: Store the current value and compare it to the new one when the event next fires. If you want more specific help, please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Let me see your code and be more specific. Then I can help you.

Comment: please provide the code which you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for checking variable value on scroll event of jquery.

```js
x = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").scroll(function(){
        $("span").text( x+= 1);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Try the scrollbar in the div</p>

<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'
</div>

<p>Scrolled <span>0</span> times.</p>

</body>
</html>
```